# I don't see the extensions directives in php.ini, yet the extensions are loaded

Tags: php, apache, configuration, centos

So i have a php.ini for our vps where none of the extensions are defined(ie "extension=php_curl.so"), yet when i look at phpinfo() on the webpage, i see all our modules/extensions are loaded(ie, curl, mbstring, imagick etc).  Where/how else can those extensions be loaded?

*EDIT*

Also in EashApache, in the php extensions section of your build/profile, it shows all the available extensions(enabled/or not).

I'm certain theres a master php.ini of some sort some where on the vps, or maybe the server the vps is on where all default php configurations are loaded by default.

Comment: Maybe the extensions are compiled into the php core. Check the ´Configure Command` section in the output of phpinfo(). If an entry looks like `with-xyz=shared` the extension is build as a shared object. But if there is no `shared` in that option it goes into the php core and is available without further extension=... directives.

Comment: u sir are right, well atleast i c some extension names in that section.  Please add as answer,  ill check it off!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensions can be compiled as shared objects which you load via an `extension=...` directive or (but shouldn't imho) via [dl()](http://docs.php.net/dl).
Extensions can also be compiled into the php core. Then they are available without further "commands".
phpinfo() gives you information about the php core in its `Configure Command` section, e.g.

> --with-pdo-oci=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,**shared**
> --with-mcrypt

The pdo_oci module is build as a shared object/dll while the mcrypt module is built into the php core.

Answer (score -1):

Extensions in directory "extension_dir" (definined in php.ini) are automatically included.

Comment: its a linux system depending on which one it probably has split configs and loads some of the php extensions from /var/lib/ or /usr/lib/ as generic system libraries.  For example ubuntu has a primary php.ini but also php5.ini and php5-fpm.ini which are included from primary php.ini and override its settings on a per instance basis. But it can be further overridden by putting additional files in /etc/php5/conf.d and /etc/php5/mods-available/ and /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d and /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini